# Java Split on Spaces and Special Characters

Tags: java, regex, split

I am trying to split a string on spaces and some specific special characters.

Given the string "john - & + $ ? . @ boy"
I want to get the array:

```
array[0]="john";
array[1]="boy";
```

I've tried several regular expressions and gotten no where. Here is my current stab:

```
String[] terms = uglString.split("\\s+|[\\-\\+\\$\\?\\.@&].*");
```

Which preserves "john" but not "boy". Can anyone get me the rest of this?

Comment: I think it's important to know what characters should be allowed in each array value; otherwise your question is quite open and vague.

Comment: That's part of the rub, I don't know them all yet.

Comment: check this out http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html and test here http://www.regexe.com/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just use:

```
String[] terms = input.split("[\\s@&.?$+-]+");
```

You can put a short-hand character class inside a character class (note the `\s`), and most meta-character loses their meaning inside a character class, except for `[`, `]`, `-`, `&`, `\`. However, `&` is meaningful only when comes in pair `&&`, and `-` is treated as literal character if put at the beginning or the end of the character class.

Other languages may have different rules for parsing the pattern, but the rule about `-` applies for most of the engines.

As @Sean Patrick Floyd mentioned in his answer, the important thing boils down to defining what constitute a word. `\w` in Java is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` (English letters upper and lower case, digits and underscore), and therefore, `\W` consists of all other characters. If you want to consider Unicode letters and digits, you may want to look at [Unicode character classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#ucc).

Answer (score 9):

You could make your code much easier by replacing your pattern with `"\\W+"` (one or more occurrences of a non-word character. (This way you are whitelisting characters instead of blacklisting, which is usually a good idea)

And of Course things could be made more efficient by using [Guava's `Splitter` class](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html)

Answer (score 2):

Try out this.....

```
Input.replace("-&+$?.@"," ").split(" ");
```

Answer (score 1):

Breaking then step by step:

For your case, you replace non-word chars (as pointed out). Now you might want to preserve the spaces for an easy String split.

```
String ugly = "john - & + $ ? . @ boy";
String words = ugly.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]", "");
```

There are a lot of spaces in the resulting String which you might want to generally trim to just 1 space:

```
String formatted = words.trim().replaceAll(" +", " ");
```

Now you can easily split the String into the words to a String Array:

```
String[] terms = formatted.split("\\s");
System.out.println(terms[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

to add to what have been said about `Splitter`, you can do something of this sort:

```
    String str = "john - & + $ ? . @ boy";
    Iterable<String> ttt = Splitter.on(Pattern.compile("\\W")).trimResults().omitEmptyStrings().split(str);
```

Comment: `\s\W` is equivalent to `\W`. Word character class does not contain spaces, so non-word character class contains spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use this format.

```
String s = "john - & + $ ? . @ boy";
String reg = "[!_.',@? ]";
String[] res = s.split(reg);
```

here include every character that you want to split inside the `[ ]` brackets.

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like below

```
arrayOfStringType=string.split(" |'|,|.|//+|_");
```

'|' will work as an or operator here.